# Не работает .htaccess, единая точка доступа

Tags: apache

Всем привет. Сделал сайт на php с MVC-архитектурой, роуты, единая точка входа, на локалке (openserver) работает хорошо. Нужно было загрузить на сервер с Ubuntu 16.02, поставил LAMP, загрузил. На локалке работает редирект на единую точку входа (index.php), на убунту ничего не работает. В чем может быть дело?

Из данных:

.htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8    

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Apache:   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на OpenServer всё работает, то, скорее всего, директивы `.htaccess` прописаны верно. Проверьте включен ли на сервере `mod_rewrite`. Чаще всего проблемы именно из-за этого.

```
$ apache2ctl -M
```

Если `mod_rewrite` отключен, подключите его:

```
$ a2enmod rewrite
```

Не забудьте после включения прописать в конфиге виртуального хоста `AllowOverride All` и перезагрузить Apache.

Comment: Да, верно, `mod_rewrite` был выключен, включил, перезапустил. Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, а где лежит конфиг хоста?))

Comment: Нашел, все сделал, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Еще бывает проблема в регистре букв, у линукса с этим все строго.